# Need help on link_to with on click event ruby on rails 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails. If anyone could help me convert this code into a ruby link_to method:

```
<a href="#top" onclick=$("#menu-close").click();>Home</a>
```

I tried to search google for an answer. But it made me more confuse on how to implement it on my site.

```
<%= link_to "Home" , {:action => "index", :controller => "welcome", :anchor => "top", :onclick => '$("#menu-close").click()' } %>
```

but still it does not close the sidebar.

Here is also the script I put below the footer :

```
$("#menu-close").click(function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active"); 
});
```

Comment: I would love to help but I am unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The code should close a sidebar when click. As you suggested I tried <%= link_to "Home" , {:action => "index", :controller => "welcome", :anchor => "top", :onclick => '$("#menu-close").click()' } %> but still it does not close the sidebar. Here is also the script I put below the footer : $("#menu-close").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });

Comment: can you edit the question add add it to the question?

Comment: you should not need to call a action or a controller on this link

Comment: Are you sure that you are hitting your js?

Comment: where do you think that the problem is at?

Comment: What does `  e.preventDefault(); ` do? is it relevant for this question?

Comment: Sorry, all the code here was not made by me. I copied it form the startbootstrap template. Specifically, the stylish portfolio template(https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-stylish-portfolio/). All the parts are working, except for the part on the sidebar menu. The menu does not close when I click a link.

Comment: I think the problem is just calling out the script for toggling off the sibebar menu off when a link is click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope what you are asking is for this

```
<%= link_to 'Home', '#top',:onclick => '$("#menu-close").click()'%>
```

---

to remove the on click and move it  you can do something like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Home', '#top',class: 'menu-close-btn'%>
```

this would be in a js file

```
$(".menu-close-btn").click(function(){
  ....
});
```

---

I created a example on github https://github.com/mzaragoza/sample-opne-close-sidebar

what I have:

Js that will open and close the page

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";   
}
```

Now some basic CSS

```
 #app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

and last but not least in the views

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <%= link_to 'X', 'javascript:void(0)', class: 'closebtn', onclick: "closeNav()" %>
  <%= link_to 'Page 1', '#' %>
  <%= link_to 'Page 2', '#' %>
  <%= link_to 'Page 3', '#' %>
  <%= link_to 'Page 4', '#' %>
</div>
```

I hope that this is able to help you out more. 
You can see how it all comes together [here](https://github.com/mzaragoza/sample-opne-close-sidebar)

Happy Coding :)

Comment: What us the UJS way

Comment: no JS in your views. so you would add a `onClick` handler to your application.js

Comment: If you do it that way, you will scroll to the top of your page as a side-effect.

Comment: the example did call to go to top

Comment: The example called to go to the `#top`, you have put '#'. Ok, you have edited now.

Comment: Yes, I need to convert the html <a> tag to an embedded ruby link_to. The syntax seems to be correct because when I tried to refresh the page in doesn't return any error. Unfortunately, It does not toggle off the sidebar. Currently watching, railcast episode #205 Unobtrusive Javascript hoping I could understand what is happening.

Comment: Thank you for the example. Finally got my app working as it should

Answer (score 1):

In your erb file put:

```
<%= link_to 'Home', '#', id: '#top' %>
```

And in some of your js files put:

```
$('#top).on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#menu-close").click()
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go.